# While loop printing too soon in Java

Tags: loops, while-loop

I am new to java and a little bit at the end of my tether with what I am trying to do, I'm sorry if this is a really daft question!
I am trying to print out a drawing area, then a number of rectangles in the drawing area from user input. However the code I have written is printing out the drawing area and 1 rectangle, then asking for the next rectangle and printing that. Can anyone help me ask for size of multiple rectangles and then print them in the drawing area at the end please? The program works but just prints at the wrong time but I can't work out what to move where.
I've included the code below for the user side of the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class DrawingUser
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   


        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inputString;

        int rows; int cols; int rowstart; 
        int rowend; int colstart; int colend; char matrix; 


        System.out.print("Input size of row for drawing area ");
        inputString = input.readLine();
        rows = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        //System.out.println("Row size is " + rows);

        System.out.print("Input size of column for drawing area ");
        inputString = input.readLine();
        cols = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        //System.out.println("column size is " + cols);

        //while statement to continue printing rectangles 
        //until negative numbers are entered for the rectangle size     
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Input start of rectangle row ");
            inputString = input.readLine();
            rowstart = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

            System.out.print("Input end of rectangle row  ");
            inputString = input.readLine();
            rowend = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

            System.out.print("Input start of rectangle column  ");
            inputString = input.readLine();
            colstart = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

            System.out.print("Input end of rectangle column  ");
            inputString = input.readLine();
            colend = Integer.parseInt(inputString);

            System.out.print("enter a character to create a rectangle ");
            String str = input.readLine();
            char a = str.length() > 0 ? str.charAt(0): '\0';

            //if statement if row/column is negative then stop
            if ((rowstart <0) || (colstart <0))
                    {break;}


        Drawing drawing = new Drawing (rows, cols, 
            rowstart, rowend, colstart, colend);

        drawing.drawArea();

        drawing.fillGrid(a);

        drawing.drawArea();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? The code above shows no attempt to ask for multiple values before printing.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? I'm very confused about the end goal.

Comment: it's a drawing program. So user enters the size of a drawing area in rows and columns and then a rectangle to be drawn with characters, user enters where they want to rectangle to start with regards to the row and column and then where the rectangle should finish. So it does that bit fine, but I need it to print more than 1 rectangle in the same drawing area, which I can't do it prints it individually. Sorry if that doesnt make sense!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loop to only execute the number of times that you want to print rectangles, then you need to get that input *before* you enter the loop.

For example...

```
System.out.print("How many rectangles  ");
inputString = input.readLine();
rectangles= Integer.parseInt(inputString);
```

And then as a condition in your loop, use...

```
while (i < rectangles)...
```

Or use a for loop...

```
for(int i=0; i < rectangles; i++)...
```